# Can anyone please explain the execution flow of this C program?

Tags: c

This program runs without any error. Explain the flow of the below program:

```
int incr(int i) //method definition
{
    static int value=0; //static variable
    value+=i;
    return(value); //returning the value
}

int main(void) {   //main function

    int i; //variable declaration
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        i= incr(i);  //method call
    printf("%d\n",i); //printing the value
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `16`

Comment: I don't know C program but it would be nice if you explain what error you getting

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program in a debugger, line by line while monitoring the values of all variables?

Comment: Note that `i++` and `i= incr(i);` both incrementing the value of `i`. What is your expected output?

Comment: And I suspect you mean that it runs *without* and error?

Comment: And if you don't have access to a debugger, it's really very simple and easy to do it all on paper! Or just print out all intermediate results.

Comment: You are incrementing your loop variable twice, and since variable `value` is statically defined as `0`, it will retain its last call value.

Comment: This looks like homework which we won't do for you. But if you have a _specific_ question, we are happy to help you out.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: `incr` should really be called `accumulate`, because it adds up the parameter values.

Answer (score 2):

i think you increment 2 times i so you have 0, 2, 4, 8, 16 .....
Add a printf inside your loop for know why you have this output. You don't even try to understand what's really happening ....

Edit i'am stupid you get 
0
1
3
7
15

after when you get out of the loop you get 16

```
int incr(int i) //method definition
{
    /**
    * At first the static will be init at 0 but when you will go back to 
      the function, the static will not be init but keep his value
     */

    static int value = 0; 
    printf("value : %d\n",i); // print 0 0 1 3 7
    value+=i;
    return(value); //returning the value
}

int main(void) {   //main function

int i; //variable declaration
for(i=0;i<10;i++) // you will increment i by i 
{ // Add brackets to see what's really happend 
     i= incr(i);  //i will be static value + i,
     printf("%d\n",i); //printing the value :0 1 3 7 15
}
 printf("%d\n",i); // print 16
 return 0;
}
```

keep it mind that a static variable in c is a global defined inside a block. i like to use a static for my main structure in my c programmes something like this :

```
struct t_foo *foo my_singleton(struct t_foo *foo)
{

      static t_foo *foo = 0;
      if (foo == 0)
           init_struct(&foo); // basically malloc with some init
      return (foo);
}
```

and in the beginning of my main :

```
 int main()
 {
   struct t_foo *foo;
   foo = my_singleton(foo);
   foo->yolo = 42;
   ...
   return (0);
  }
```

and in any function of my programm i can do :

```
void any_function(void)
{
      struct t_foo *foo = 0;
      foo = my_singleton(); 
      /**
        Now i can access everithing that was inside my struct
      */
      printf("%d\n", foo->yolo); // print 42
}
```

It's pretty useful when you some library function or signal and you can't pass you're structure in argument.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15556998)

Comment: you're right i 'll edit for trying to explain more what a static variable stand for in c

Answer (score -1):

Add `{}` after the `for` loop and then write code between them.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure how this explains the output of the code as per the question?